# Google Chrome and Safari on MacOS grabs the character preceding the selected text when you drag'n'drop it into <textarea>

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, textarea

Clean textarea code (as in sandbox) without any side factors (like scripts and specific styles) its work via drag'n'drop in the Chrome browser is followed by a strange phenomenon.

```html
<textarea cols="80" rows="10">
row1w1 row1w2 row1w3 row1w4 row1w5
row2w1 row2w2 row2w3 row2w4 row2w5
row3w1 row3w2 row3w3 row3w4 row3w5
row4w1 row4w2 row4w3 row4w4 row4w5
row5w1 row5w2 row5w3 row5w4 row5w5
row6w1 row6w2 row6w3 row6w4 row6w5
row7w1 row7w2 row7w3 row7w4 row7w5
</textarea>
```

For example, I drag the first word from any line somewhere like in the GIF image.

[image: Google Chrome grabs the previous character during drag-n-drop in textarea]

Along with the word, for some reason the drag-n-drop event grabs the character before the word (in this case, it's a line break character), even though that character was not selected.  It is "compensated", if I may say so, by a space put before the word inserted in the new place. In some cases, this space can stand before the word, after the word and even turn into two spaces on both sides of the word, and sometimes does not appear at all.

The actual question is. Is there a way to make Chrome behave like a text editor or like Firefox? Is there a standard somewhere, or at least some description of how the phenomenon works, when it puts a space and when it doesn't?

[image: Expected behavior of drag-n-drop with textarea]

I tried to solve this problem with a script. But the code works very crudely. For example, I can not track the difference between moving the selected text one character forward or backward. I think there is a better solution.

```js
// If Google Chrome used
if (/Chrome/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
  // This variable handles source drag info 
  let dragging = null;
  // This flag indicates whether the browser has captured a character before the word
  let captureFlag = null;
  
  // DragStart event handler
  textarea.ondragstart = (e) => {
    // First of all, аt this point we can read the initial state before dragging
    const {
      value,
      selectionStart,
      selectionEnd
    } = textarea;
    // Selected text
    const selectionData = value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    // And keep the symbol before of the selected word
    const selectionBefore = selectionStart ? value[selectionStart - 1] : '';
    dragging = {
      selectionStart,
      selectionEnd,
      selectionData,
      selectionBefore
    };
  }
  // Input event handler
  textarea.oninput = (e) => {
    // When dragging, this event is triggered twice
    if (e.inputType == 'deleteByDrag') {
      // At this point the highlighted word has already been deleted.
      const {
        selectionStart
      } = textarea;
      // If the cursor moved one character backward, 
      // the browser has definitely captured this character
      captureFlag = dragging && selectionStart == (dragging.selectionStart - 1);
    } else if (e.inputType == 'insertFromDrop') {
      // At this point, the selected word is already inserted in its new location.
      if (dragging) {
        // Chrome browser leaves the word selected.
        const {
          value,
          selectionStart,
          selectionEnd
        } = textarea;
        // First we cut out what is inserted from the value
        let newValue = value.substr(0, selectionStart) + value.substr(selectionEnd);
        // If the browser does grab a character before selecting
        if (captureFlag && dragging.selectionStart > 0) {
          // Let's calculate his position
          const insertPos = dragging.selectionStart - 1;
          // Put the missing symbol back in place
          newValue = newValue.substr(0, insertPos) +
            dragging.selectionBefore +
            newValue.substr(insertPos);
        }

        // Next, we have to determine the offset.
        // If the pasted text was inserted somewhere after the deletion, 
        // we need to add to the offset one character that we just inserted
        const offset = (captureFlag && (selectionStart > dragging.selectionStart)) ? 1 : 0;

        // Now let's count the positions where we insert the originally selected text 
        const newSelectionStart = selectionStart + offset;
        const newSelectionEnd = dragging.selectionEnd - dragging.selectionStart +
          selectionStart + offset;

        // Insert text that was originally selected (still in the dragstart event) 
        newValue = newValue.substr(0, newSelectionStart) +
          dragging.selectionData +
          newValue.substr(newSelectionStart);

        // Apply the new value
        textarea.value = newValue;
        // And let's select this area of text like the browser
        textarea.setSelectionRange(newSelectionStart, newSelectionEnd, "none");
      }
    }
  }
  // Reset the variables when the drag is finished
  textarea.ondragend = () => {
    dragging = null;
    captureFlag = null
  };
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" cols="80" rows="10">
row1w1 row1w2 row1w3 row1w4 row1w5
row2w1 row2w2 row2w3 row2w4 row2w5
row3w1 row3w2 row3w3 row3w4 row3w5
row4w1 row4w2 row4w3 row4w4 row4w5
row5w1 row5w2 row5w3 row5w4 row5w5
row6w1 row6w2 row6w3 row6w4 row6w5
row7w1 row7w2 row7w3 row7w4 row7w5
</textarea>
```

**UPDATE**

I was fixed to track the dragging of the word one character backward or forward.

```js
// If Google Chrome used
if (/Chrome/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
  // This variable handles source drag info 
  let dragging = null;
  // This flag indicates whether the browser has captured a character before the word
  let captureFlag = null;
  
  // DragStart event handler
  textarea.ondragstart = (e) => {
    // First of all, аt this point we can read the initial state before dragging
    const {
      value,
      selectionStart,
      selectionEnd
    } = textarea;
    // Selected text
    const selectionData = value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    // And keep the symbol before of the selected word
    const selectionBefore = selectionStart ? value[selectionStart - 1] : '';
    // Save drag position
    dragging = {
      selectionStart,
      selectionEnd,
      selectionData,
      selectionBefore,
      dragLayerX: e.layerX,
      dragLayerY: e.layerY,
      dropLayerX: -1,
      dropLayerY: -1,
    };
  }
  // drop event handler
  textarea.ondrop = (e) => {
    // Save drop position
    dragging.dropLayerX = e.layerX;
    dragging.dropLayerY = e.layerY;
  }
  // Input event handler
  textarea.oninput = (e) => {
    // When dragging, this event is triggered twice
    if (e.inputType == 'deleteByDrag') {
      // At this point the highlighted word has already been deleted.
      const {
        selectionStart
      } = textarea;
      // If the cursor moved one character backward, 
      // the browser has definitely captured this character
      captureFlag = dragging && selectionStart == (dragging.selectionStart - 1);
    } else if (e.inputType == 'insertFromDrop') {
      // At this point, the selected word is already inserted in its new location.
      if (dragging) {
        // Chrome browser leaves the word selected.
        const {
          value,
          selectionStart,
          selectionEnd
        } = textarea;
        // First we cut out what is inserted from the value
        let newValue = value.substr(0, selectionStart) + value.substr(selectionEnd);
        // If the browser does grab a character before selecting
        if (captureFlag && dragging.selectionStart > 0) {
          // Let's calculate his position
          const insertPos = dragging.selectionStart - 1;
          // Put the missing symbol back in place
          newValue = newValue.substr(0, insertPos) +
            dragging.selectionBefore +
            newValue.substr(insertPos);
        }

        // Next, we have to determine the offset.
        let offset;
        // If text was dragged from end of row and dropped to start of next row
        if(selectionStart == dragging.selectionStart){
          offset = 1;
        }
        // If text was dragging on one char backward or forward
        // It was need to be calculated
        else if(selectionStart - dragging.selectionStart == -1){
          // First of all, lets calculate one text line height
          let ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
          ctx.font = getComputedStyle(textarea).font; 
          const measure = ctx.measureText(textarea.value);
          const lineHeight = measure.fontBoundingBoxAscent + measure.fontBoundingBoxDescent;
          // Then set offset 0 if text moved backward or 2 if forward
          if(Math.abs(dragging.dragLayerY - dragging.dropLayerY) > 0.6 * lineHeight){
            offset = dragging.dragLayerY < dragging.dropLayerY ? 2 : 0;
          }
          else {
            offset = dragging.dragLayerX < dragging.dropLayerX ? 2 : 0;
          }
        }
        else {
          // If the pasted text was inserted somewhere after the deletion, 
          // we need to add to the offset one character that we just inserted
          offset = (captureFlag && (selectionStart > dragging.selectionStart)) ? 1 : 0;
        }

        // Now let's count the positions where we insert the originally selected text 
        const newSelectionStart = selectionStart + offset;
        const newSelectionEnd = dragging.selectionEnd - dragging.selectionStart +
          selectionStart + offset;

        // Insert text that was originally selected (still in the dragstart event) 
        newValue = newValue.substr(0, newSelectionStart) +
          dragging.selectionData +
          newValue.substr(newSelectionStart);

        // Apply the new value
        textarea.value = newValue;
        // And let's select this area of text like the browser
        textarea.setSelectionRange(newSelectionStart, newSelectionEnd, "none");
      }
    }
  }
  // Reset the variables when the drag is finished
  textarea.ondragend = () => {
    dragging = null;
    captureFlag = null
  };
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" cols="80" rows="10">
row1w1 row1w2 row1w3 row1w4 row1w5
row2w1 row2w2 row2w3 row2w4 row2w5
row3w1 row3w2 row3w3 row3w4 row3w5
row4w1 row4w2 row4w3 row4w4 row4w5
row5w1 row5w2 row5w3 row5w4 row5w5
row6w1 row6w2 row6w3 row6w4 row6w5
row7w1 row7w2 row7w3 row7w4 row7w5
</textarea>
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the initial bug on chrome. :/

Comment: I have version 94.0.4606.71 (arm64). All extensions are disabled.

Comment: @GhostPengy Maybe it depends on the operating system. I have MacOS Big Sur 11.6 (20G165)

Comment: @GhostPengy I reset all browser settings, flags, users. The problem occurs even in incognito mode. Too bad I can not run any virtual machine on this computer. I will buy another computer tomorrow.

Comment: Can't reproduce either in Chrome 94.0.4606.61, Edge 94.0.992.38, or Firefox 94.0.992.38. I'm on Windows 11, though - might this be an issue with drag and drop on MacOS specifically?

Comment: It seems to be really mac OS behavior. In Firefox and Edge it works as usual. But in Chrome, Chromium and Safari these symptoms are observed. I also tried to reproduce this in MacOS text editors like XCode and some other native MacOS programs. In all programs, notes, text editors it works as usual. This phenomenon seems to be done only for macOS browsers. But who came up with the thought that doing it this way is a good idea? I can not find an explanation for it. I'm so tired of these special things with macOS. I think I should close the question somehow.

Comment: Apple does many things which make no sense. But again, they always liked to be the special boy. Sadly cannot help you, since I am not running any Apple software. Perhaps some apple specific forums could help you?

Comment: @GhostPengy If this functionality is Apple's responsibility, I probably won't be able to disable it with HTML. So I will have to adapt the initial script to Chrome and Safari on MacOS. The crutch is already written. I even wrote mocha tests. My task is to make an interface for text proofreaders. Most likely, the interface itself doesn't have to work on macOS.
But I would like it to work on my computer.

Comment: You should change the question title including this is specific to MacOS.